# Protractor - Start Selenium server on given port

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor

Below configuration is not starting the server on given port. It' starting the server on its own port every time by protractor.

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

multiCapabilities: [ {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles: true,
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
  seleniumPort: 4455,
  seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60']
  }
]
}
```

**Output**:

```
[11:06:47] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:06:48] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://127.0.0.1:60315/wd/hub
```

Expecting server to be started on port 4455.

Comment: Use `localSeleniumStandaloneOpts` . Check this https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Comment: No, still having the same issue with localSeleniumStandaloneOpts option.

Comment: Have you tried just using "port" instead of "seleniumPort"

Comment: why do you keep seleniumServerJar inside multiCababilities? any reason

Comment: so that I can specify a different port for different capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-
               manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',

localSeleniumStandaloneOpts:{
         port: 4455,
         args:['-browserTimeout=60']

       }  


multiCapabilities: [ {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
  }
]}
```